# what is zookeeper.broker.path

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm learning Spark and Kafka and came across this project [kafka-spark-consumer](https://github.com/dibbhatt/kafka-spark-consumer) that seems to consume messages from Kafka efficiently. This project requires to configure few kafka & zookeeper properties thats where I'm struggling. I mean what does this property mean **zookeeper.broker.path**? Sorry, if its a basic question.

I have configured kafka in single node and with the following properties,

```
broker.id=1
port=9093
log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

and zookeeper as,

```
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181/brokers
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

if i try to configure the zookeeper.broker.path with /brokers i get the following exception from the consumer,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/<name>/partitions
    at consumer.kafka.ReceiverLauncher.getNumPartitions(ReceiverLauncher.java:217)
    at consumer.kafka.ReceiverLauncher.createStream(ReceiverLauncher.java:79)
    at consumer.kafka.ReceiverLauncher.launch(ReceiverLauncher.java:51)
    at com.ibm.spark.streaming.KafkaConsumer.run(KafkaConsumer.java:78)
    at com.ibm.spark.streaming.KafkaConsumer.start(KafkaConsumer.java:43)
    at com.ibm.spark.streaming.KafkaConsumer.main(KafkaConsumer.java:103)
```

Can you help me to understand what is the zookeeper broker path here and how can i configure that?

**EDIT**

The above error is caused due to non-existent topic, the moment i created the topic, the error went away.

As answered by user007, the /brokers directory is created by zookeeper by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of **'/brokers'** for zookeeper.connect property. It should be

`zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181`

I am not familiar with the "kafka-spark-consumer" project which you mentioned. But usually **/brokers** is the default node kafka creates in zookeeper. I haven't seen any library asking the user to configure it.

**/brokers** is the znode path under which metadata like topics are stored.

Go to kafka **bin** directory. Then invoke zookeeper shell - `./zookeeper-shell.sh  localhost`

Then do `ls`. You should be able to see `topics` and other child nodes created there.

Comment: Kafka is bit tricky to configure over zookeeper but it always need configuration. Take a look at the oryx project for more details about that use case!